# How to import single utility form Bootstrap 5

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I've tried to import a single utility like "margin" or "margin-top" from Bootstrap 5 but I am not able to achieve it. Is there a way to import only a specific set of classes? Please don't give me links to https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/spacing/ - if it was enough, I wouldn't ask here.

Comment: Have you checked out the section on [unused css](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/customize/optimize/#unused-css)? Instead of importing just the utilities you need you can instead purge the css you didn't use.

Comment: @RobertCorponoi "unused" could be a good idea, but only for optimization. If I want to do this during development/rebuild it will be like "remove 100 000 classes, keep 8" - this is not a highly effective way. I think, there is a way to achieve it (I can feel it :) ) but I don't know how.

Comment: It would be something that you would run on build, before deploying to production so you don't have to worry about development. Other than that, your best bet is [importing just the styles you need into your SCSS file](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/customize/optimize/#lean-sass-imports), which is also an optimization.